# Cut and Paste in Eclipse Package/Navigator view

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, cut-and-paste

How cut and past operation can be done in eclipse Package/Navigator view in a similar way we do it any **file explorer**. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> is not working.

In Navigator view we have **Move..** context menu option but it is not a quick way, also **Move..** option is not available on Package explorer. Any external plugins available to do this?.

Note that I can cut a file/folder in any file explorer and paste in eclipse project/package/folder but inside/within eclipse it is not working.

Comment: Move... option is available in package explorer, under Refactor... --> Move...

Comment: Yes. It refractors i.e update the references. Not do simple cut & paste.